# Armed to the teeth

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

> Drop two from the left
>   I can be out of this world 
>   Two more from the right 
>   I might get hurled
>
> Drop two in-between 
>   I’ll be hollow in form 
>   Two more from the right 
>   I may keep you warm

Who am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess:

> **Sprocket**

Drop two from the left
I can be out of this world

> **Rocket**: can be launched into space

Two more from the right
I might get hurled

> **Rock**: might be thrown

Drop two in-between
I’ll be hollow in form

> **Socket**: is essentially a hole that something fits into

Two more from the right
I may keep you warm

> **Sock**: keeps your feet warm

Armed to the teeth

> Sprockets are the teeth of gears